# Singular value decomposition of weighted matrix

Tags: svd

If I compute the singular value decomposition of a matrix A and then want to compute the SVD of a matrix A' that is the same as A except that each row is scaled by a different number, is there a more efficient way of computing the SVD of A', given the SVD of A, than just starting from scratch?

For example, given the SVD of with elements

```
a11 a12
a21 a22
a31 a32
```

I want to efficiently compute the SVD of a matrix with elements

```
c1*a11 c1*a12
c2*a21 c2*a22
c3*a31 c3*a32
```